# Iterate following Json using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to iterate following json inside ng-repeat but not working. I would like to get both Ques and img. Below, I have tried "Ques" part but it doesn't display anything.

```
[{
    "Ques": [{
        "column1": "3",
        "column2": "ok?"
    }, {
        "column1": "4",
        "column2": "test"
    }],
    "img": [{
        "column1": "21",
        "column2": "CDH.PNG"
    }, {
        "column1": "22",
        "column2": "Feedback.PNG"
    }]
}]
```

My code given below

```
 var messages = JSON.stringify(response.data);
            $scope.messages = JSON.parse(messages);

 <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in messages.Ques">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.column2}}</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">{{item.column1}}</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way. Its working. I can also use "Img" same like below.

```
 <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in messages">
                <div ng-repeat="items in item['Ques']">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{items.column2}}</h4>
                    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{items.column1}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```